# Mongoose query return null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to get a response from mongodb.  I am using node.js and mongodb with the help of mongoose.

In my node.js app I have

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author  : ObjectId,
    title   : String,
    slug    : { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true },
    content : String,
    summary : String,
    date    : Date
})

var BlogModel = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPost);

BlogModel.find({}, function(docs){
   console.log(docs);
});
```

If I type show dbs in the mongo shell I get

```
admin   (empty)
myDB       0.203125GB
local   (empty)
test    (empty)
```

db.blogmodel.find() returns :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50108d3df57b0e3375a20479"), "title" : "FirstPost" }
```

and yes I do have mongod running.

**Fixed Solution**

```
var BlogModel = mongoose.model('blogmodel', BlogPost, 'blogmodel');
```

It works because its (model name, schema name, collection name)

Comment: This issue has driven me crazy! I added credit for your fixed solution part!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Mongoose pluralizes model names so it's running `find` on the "blogposts" collection instead of "blogpost". That said, your query in the mongo shell is on the "blogmodel" collection. In that case:

```
var BlogModel = mongoose.Model("BlogModel", ..)
```

or pass the collection name as the third param:

```
var BlogModel = mongoose.model("BlogPost", schema, "blogmodel")
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had to change it to the above fix but your post helped me solve it so i'll give you the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Why isn't this in the mongoose docs? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 6):

The first parameter to your `BlogModel.find` callback is `err`, the second parameter is `docs`.  So your code should be:

```
BlogModel.find({}, function(err, docs){
   console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: Does the `BlogPosts` collection contain documents if you query it from the mongo shell?

Comment: I added it to the original post and yes I have one document for testing, Which I can't find for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still experiencing this issue even after checking the accepted answer – make sure your database connection url contains the database name, e.g. for database name `myDB`...

```js
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB`)
```

I'd forgotten it and my mongoose searches were all returning null or empty arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar error yesterday, in my case error was caused by data imported to mongo. After I used mongoimport key _id was stored as string instead of ObjectId. When I was querying data in mongo everything works well, but in Mongoose when I was trying find something by _id it always returned null or empty Array. I hope that info might by useful for someone.