# Mongoose Blank Query finds all, but specific query fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am writing a small server with express, mongo and mongoose. My code:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const COLOURS = ["e6194b", "3cb44b", "ffe119", "0082c8", "f58231", "911eb4", "46f0f0", "d2f53c", "fabebe", "e6beff"];

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
    mongoose.connect(url);

    var app = express();

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        console.log('Database connected and open');
    });

    var deviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        mac: String,
        ip: String,
        colourIndex: Number
    });
    var Device = mongoose.model('Device', deviceSchema);

    app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
        console.log("Registration: ");
        console.log("    MAC: " + req.query.mac);
        console.log("    IP : " + req.query.ip);
        Device.find({ mac: /req.query.mac/ }, function(err, deviceList) {
            if (err || deviceList.length == 0) {
                console.log("  Cannot find " + req.query.mac + ": " + err);
                Device.count({ mac: /req.query.mac/ }, function( err, count){
                    var index = count;
                    console.log("There are " + count + " matching");
                    var device = new Device({ mac: req.query.mac, ip: req.query.ip, colourIndex: index });
//                  device.save(function (err, device) {
//                      if (err) {
//                          res.status(500).send("Internal error");
//                          return console.error(err);
//                      }
//                      res.status(202).send(COLOURS[index]);
//                  });
                    res.status(202).send(COLOURS[0]);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(deviceList);
                res.status(202).send("Success");      
                console.log("  Colour index: %s", deviceList[0].colourIndex);
            }
        });
    });
```

When I try to use `mac: /req.query.mac/` to find the device, it fails **EVERY** time. If I leave it blank, it does return the devices (I added duplicates to check with the commented out code).

I have tried looking at the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) and [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661590/mongoose-query-return-null)

Comment: While the answer may match, I do feel that people in my position won't even know how to begin asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/.../` notation doesn't expand variables into their values, so you are *literally* searching for the string `req.query.mac` (although `.` will match any character).

You need to create a regular expression instance from the variable's value, which you can do using the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
Device.find({ mac: new RegExp(req.query.mac) }, ...)
```

(and similarly for `Device.count()`)

It's advisable to use a module like [`escape-string-regexp`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-string-regexp) to properly escape the string first, given that it's external input (`req.query.mac` may contains characters that have special meaning in regular expression patterns, and some patterns may be abused to cause a denial-of-service attack):

```
const escapeStringRegexp = require('escape-string-regexp');
...
Device.find({ mac: new RegExp(escapeStringRegexp(req.query.mac)) }, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured that out :(